# Javascript: Find the word in string with most occurances of a single letter

Tags: javascript, string, function, character

I've got this function to seperate the string by word:

```
function LetterCount(str) {
var words = str.split(" ");
var letters;
var i;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      letters = words[i].split("");
     }
}
```

and this function to search a string and count each letter:

```
function charFreq(s) {
  var i, j;
  var a = new Array();

  for (j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i][0] == s[j]) {
         a[i][1]++;
               break;
        }
    }

    if (i == a.length) {

      a[i] = [s[j], 1];
    }
  }

  return a;
}
```

Struggling with figuring out a way to use these codes synchronously to figure out which word in the words array has the most repeated letter.

Comment: What's `j` in the `LetterCount` function?

Comment: just a placeholder variable to sort through the inputted string

Comment: But you never set it before doing `letters[j] = ...`.

Comment: ooops, it was some left over variable from a previous attempt, sorry, deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var all_words = str.split(' ');
var all_freq = all_words.map(charFreq);
var max_freq = 0;
var max_word;
for (var i = 0; i < all_freq.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < all_freq[i].length; j++) {
        if (all_freq[i][j][1] > max_freq) {
            max_freq = all_freq[i][j][1];
            max_word = i;
        }
    }
}
console.log("Word with most repeats is "+all_words[max_word]);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/UsJsy/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this does what you're looking for:

```
count = function(ary) { return [].reduce.call(ary, function(o, x) { return o[x] = (o[x]||0) + 1,  o }, {}) }

text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium lobortis arcu, eget rhoncus est commodo sit amet."

letter = "o"

max = text.split(" ").reduce(function(max, word) { return count(word)[letter] > count(max)[letter] ? word : max })

console.log(max) // "commodo"
```

Some useful code just for me

```
// how to write `max(words, key=lambda w: max(Counter(w).values()))` in js

max = function(xs, key) {
    // strictly speaking, there's no need to be schwartzian here, but it's nicer this way
    return xs.map(function(x) {
        return [x, key ? key(x) : x]
    }).reduce(function(m, v) {
        return v[1] > m[1] ? v : m
    })[0];
}

counter = function(xs) {
    return [].reduce.call(xs, function(o, x) {
        return o[x] = (Number(o[x]) || 0) + 1, o
    }, {});
}

values = function(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).map(function(x) { return o[x] })
}

words = "foo bar bbarb foxx abc".split(" ")
word = max(words, function(w) { return max(values(counter(w)))})
// bbarb
```

Comment: That finds the word with the most uses of "o", not the most repeated letters in general (e.g. "mississippi").

Comment: I'm too scrubby to even understand all the shorthand =[